# How to get data from next screen using textInput on to a previous screen which use only Text field in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

**This is my code . Its just a simple testing screen. Navigation is done on both screens. Im beginner so im not familiar with redux. I want that when the user input the text on second screen  the same text will appear on first  screen as User Name  when user switch to go back from second to first screen. Kindly help me. Thanks.**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

    class FirstScreen extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text> UserNAme </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default FirstScreen;



    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {View, TextInput} from 'react-native';

    class SecondScreen extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <TextInput/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SecondScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service file, PubSub (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js) or you can store the value in the local store in the second screen and retrieve in the first screen.

Store value in a local store as below:

```
try {
       await AsyncStorage.setItem(
           key,
           value
       )

   } catch (error) {
   }
```

Retrieve value :

```
try {
        return await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
    } catch (error) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any global store/state, therefore to pass the value to the previous screen you can pass it as a param while navigating to previous screen and use it there.

But if you have the requirement of using a value on multiple screens, you should use a global state/store. (you can use mobx as it is easy to learn and can be used for small applications)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. Using `Redux`. Redux gives you ability to save data and access it in any screen.
2. You can pass a callback function to next screen and call it in second screen before `pop` function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class FirstScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.username}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  callback(username) {
    this.setState({ username });
  }

  goToSecondScreen() {
    // Depends on your navigation library
    navigation.push('SecondScreen', {
      callback: this.callback,
    });
  }
}

export default FirstScreen;

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class SecondScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  onChangeText(text) {
    this.setState({ text });
  }

  goBack() {
    this.props.callback && this.props.callback(this.state.text);
    navigation.pop();
  }
}

export default SecondScreen;
```

Comment: Can u explain little bit more about callback function ? Please

Answer (score 0):

1) by using state we can transfer data one component to another component

```
 this.setState({
 userName: val.userName,
 userId: val.userId
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state

2) Window localStorage Property

by using localStorage in javascript we can store item and get for where you want

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using redux. Redux allows you to manage all of the states in one place. Async storage is also an option but it is not recommended. If you use react navigation, the best way to do is pass the data to next screen like this.

```
navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', { myText: 'My text' });
```

You can change 'My Text' to your state variable.
And on the next screen, you access the data using

```
navigation.getParam('myText') //exact name of the key that was passed in previous screen.
```

This would return you the value that was passed in previous screen